# NextJS 13, Pocketbase Auth and middleware

Tags: authentication, next.js, server-side-rendering, middleware, pocketbase

Can someone explain how i can auth guard my app using Next JS 13 middleware? My app would be using a mix of SSR and CSR. I have not come across any kind of solution so far.